# how to send variable value from one page to another

Tags: javascript

I am trying to send an information from one page to another through javascript file
the information will only contain a value of single variable.

how to accomplish this?
I dont want to send it through query string as the value will be visible in the URL.
is there any other way?

Comment: use window.localstorage or cookie then

Comment: The value will be visible either way to anyone who cares to look in the right places. If it's Javascript, it's all client side and *cannot* be hidden from the user.

Comment: You can use either cookie or parameters to pass the data.

Comment: @deceze there's a lot of difference between it being right there in the URL bar vs hidden away behind the JS console

Comment: @N.Smeding the OP specifically said they _don't_ want it in the query string

Comment: @Alnitak Sure, but it doesn't change anything about the actual *"security"*. It *does* change something about the *behaviour*, whether the request is RESTful, whether the URL can be shared or not, and how state is preserved. OP hasn't clarified anything about those requirements, and those should greatly influence the decision here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save your data in `LocalStorage` and retrieve it on the other page.

```
localStorage.yourData = '{ test:"data" }';

console.log(localStorage['yourData']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to do that.

Depending on what browser is used, using `localStorage` is an option

```
//localStorage ONLY stores flat key:value pairs and can't contain Objects
localStorage.myString = "hello world";
localStorage.myObject = JSON.stringify({ foo: "bar" });

//Reading back the values is simple aswell
var myString = localStorage.myString;
var myObject = JSON.parse(localStorage.myObject);
```

Another method would be using a hash or query string. For example, you could redirect to `www.yourdomain.com/your/path?myValue=1234`
And then parse that by reading the search value from `window.location.search` (Will return `?myValue=1234` in that case) and splitting it on `=`:

```
var myValue = window.location.search.split("=")[1];
```

Another option is using hashes, similar to query params. Or even cookies.

BUT, all these methods will expose the value to the user, so if he wants to get that value, he will be able to!

Answer (score 0):

At first, as other answers, use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` to store global data.

Otherwise, you can add an event listener to detect the change of the storage value  in your target page as follow:

```
window.addEventListener('storage', (e) => console.log(e.key, e.oldValue, e.newValue))
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API#Responding_to_storage_changes_with_the_StorageEvent